# Ruby - Address of all required files from a specific root

Tags: ruby, require

I have a ruby program with multiples of modules. All of these modules use other modules with `require 'path_form_a_specific_root'`.
For example:

dir0/ has 'test1.rb' and 'test2.rb'.

dir0/dir1/ has 'test3.rb'.

dir0/dir1/dir2 has 'test4.rb'.

'test3.rb' uses `require 'dir0\test1'` and `require 'dir0\test2'` in order to use 'test1.rb' and 'test2.rb'.

Also, 'test4.rb' uses `require 'dir0\dir1\test3'` in order to use 'test3.rb''.

All of these path starts with 'dir0'. I want to convert these path independent of 'dir0'.

Answer (score 1):

You can start your program with `ruby -I dir0/ <entry_point>`

In this case all of your modules are in the load path and you just need

```
require 'module_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

One might use [`require_relative`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) instead of `require` to use relative paths instead of root-based:

**dir0/dir1/test3.rb**

```
%w|test1 test2|.each { |f| require_relative "../#{f}" }
```

**dir0/dir1/dir2/test4.rb**

```
require_relative "../test3"
```

---

The other way round would be to create the “require_all” helper:

**test_all.rb**

```
Dir['*/**/*.rb'].each &Kernel.method(:require)
```

and use `require 'test_all'` everywhere in nested files.